# Contact form design issue in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to code the below contact form in HTML&CSS.. The issue is how to make the inputs, textarea and the post button in one container and at by taking in consideration that there is a label for each one (out of the container).

[image]

For the name, the label is on the right. And it's on the left for the email. Then, the textarea label is stick to the top (I tried using bottom:100px with position:relative and it works) but I'm looking for more ideal solution.

Please find the code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shadeed9/wa7xs9vu/1/): (see full screen for better view)

Input group CSS:

```
.post .contact form .input-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

PS: The layout should be responsive and work on all screens.

Thanks,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wa7xs9vu/3/  <br/>... text should be above inputs for when zoomed in on mobile devices.

Comment: @shadeed9 Are you trying to make it responsive also?

Comment: @KK Yes I want it to be responsive.

Comment: @shadeed9 in that case you can try mine answer and make it responsive by altering the css of psuedo elements. First try if it suits your needs.

Comment: @KK Can you please double check the fiddle? the fields overlap over each other. Maybe because of the 100% width to contact class?

Comment: @shadeed9 Yes because of the width. You can restrict the width if you want. Or maybe just use media queries to make it responsive

Comment: @KK The only thing needed is to give a fluid width to the input text and textarea. How can we achieve that without affecting the labels?

Comment: Refer this answer to make it fluid using css media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Bootstrap classes but are also creating custom css. Yet there's no link to the Bootstrap css in the fiddle. There's better control if you are familiar with the grid system in Bootstrap and use that plus some custom css.

1. First you layout the form as it should be stacked on small
   viewports.
2. Then at the min-width media query of your choice, based on the grid
   classes used in the form, and how wide the labels are when they are
   outside the form you create the styles pushing out the labels.
3. Choose a max-width on the .post it's the largest for the 992px (col-md) and 1200px (col-lg)

## DEMO: http://jsbin.com/vefufi/1/

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="post">
 <div class="contact">
   <div class="title">
      <h2>Post a comment</h2>
   </div>
   <form class="comment-form">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <label class="name">Use Your Real Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <label class="email">Email Will Not Be Published</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
         </div>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
         <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
            <label class="message">Write a good comment</label>
            <textarea name="" class="form-control" cols="47" rows="7" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
           <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success">Button</button>
        </div>        
        
      </div>
   </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.post {
    padding: 0 1.5% /* matches the column and -margin values */
}
.comment-form .form-control {
    border: 0px;
    background: #eee;
    min-height: 50px; /* make the .form-control taller */
}
.comment-form > .row {
    margin: 0 -1.5%; /* negative margin on row for new, fluid gutter */
}
.comment-form [class*="col-"] {
        padding: 0 1.5% /* new fluid gutter to tighten up the space between col-X-6 */
}


@media (min-width:992px) { 
    .post {
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .comment-form label {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
    }
    .comment-form .name {
        left: -90%;
        top: 8px;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .comment-form .email {
        right: -90%;
        top: 8px;
    }
    .comment-form .message {
        left: -45%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -16px;
        text-align: right;
    }
}


@media (min-width:1200px) { 
    .post {
        max-width: 525px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have done it correctly, positioning the labels absolutely relative to container. There isn't any other great way, but if you could use a grid framework like kraken or others you could 
use grids to lay it out. 
Please be sure to check it on mobile devices if you're making the labels on the right.
They should cascade down therefore I assume you're not supporting lower res's

Grid example:
http://cferdinandi.github.io/kraken/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using pseudo elements, you can try this approach:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/wa7xs9vu/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="contact col-lg-6">
        <div class="title">
             <h2>Post a comment</h2>
        </div>
        <form>
            <div class="input-group name">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group email">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group message">
                <textarea name="" id="" cols="47" rows="7" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can remove labels from html.

**CSS:**

```
.col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
.post .contact {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.post .contact .title {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.post .contact form {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.post .contact form .input-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align:top; //added
}
.post .contact form .input-group label {
    color: #8e8e8e;
}
.post .contact form .input-group input[type="text"] {
    background: #ebebeb;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.post .contact form .input-group textarea {
    background: #ebebeb;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.post .contact form .post {
    width: 100%;
    background: #3eb3a5;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.post .contact form .full {
    width: 100%;
}
.post .contact form .half {
    width: 100%;
}
.post .contact form .half input[type="text"] {
    width: 48%;
}
.post .contact form .name input[type="text"] {
    float: left;
}
/*New CSS */
.name:before{
    content:"Use Your Real Name";
    position:absolute;
    right:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    top:15px;
    font:inherit;
    color:grey;
    padding: 0 5px;   

}
.email:after{
    content:"Email Will Not Be Published";
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    top:15px;
    font:inherit;
    color:grey;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.message:before{
    content:"Write a good comment";
    position:absolute;
    right:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    top:15px;
    font:inherit;
    color:grey;
    padding: 0 5px;   

}
```